ERROR Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if: * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder
Error Details full-
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes
› Opening on Android...

index.js
 import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
 import App from './App';

 // registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);  
 // It also ensures that whether you load the app in Expo Go or in a native build,
 // the environment is set up appropriately 
 registerRootComponent(App);

AppEntry.js , from nodeModules/expo/AppEntry.js :-
 import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';
 import App from '../../App'; 
 registerRootComponent(App);

